QLineEdit в PyQt5
напишите пожалуйста как работать с модулем QLineEdit в основе библиотеки PyQt5
будет вполне достаточно того,что вы напишите метод ее создания(просто создания)и пример работы с ней (можно условные конструкции)

QLineEdit - это класс, который наследуется от виджета QWidget и имеет определенные атрибуты и методы. Подробнее читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html Работайте с классом QLineEdit() как с любым другим классом. Если у вас есть конкретный вопрос или у вас что-то не получается - спросите об этом, изменив ваш вопрос.

я уже разобрался,вопрос видимо был не совсем понятен.я имел в виду обычное использование QLineEdit ,типа его простого отображение.благодарю за ответ.
